# I try to position my header straight in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i try to add logo in my html code, i dont know way bat my logo image is displayed worng, I want to be straight. my actual html is :

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        <div class="header-logo">
          <h1><a href="/"><img src="/static/logo.png" alt="SelfMarket" /></a></h1>
        </div>


          <li class="pull-right" style="margin-left: 20px;">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" id="accountDropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong>Login <span class="caret"></span></strong></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">   
              <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </li>
        <li class="pull-right"><span class="btn disabled">1 BTC = 372.59 USD</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

live demo : https://selfmarket.net/

I want to be positioned horizontally linear, where im wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your logo into a list item.

```
<li class="pull-left">
  <div class="header-logo">
    <h1><a href="/"><img src="/static/logo.png" alt="SelfMarket"></a></h1>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS attribute `text-align: center` on the h1 element that your logo is inside of to achieve this effect.